# Переход с svn на git

Tags: git, svn

В svn репозитории имеется несколько сотен проектов, над которыми работают десятки разработчиков. Будем считать что в данном репозитории нет веток и тегов, есть только trunk, а исходники хранятся в кодировках cp866 и windows-1251.

Задача - плавный перенос этих проектов на gitlab с историей и с синхронизацией в обе стороны до полной готовности потушить svn сервер.

Для начала был получен файл соответствия пользователей, затем

```
git svn clone --trunk=trunk/project1 --prefix=svn/ --localtime --authors-file=users.txt https://svn_server/svn project1
git remote add origin git@git_server:git_group/project1.git
git push origin --all
```

И тут возникает проблема и вопросы:

1. В гитлабе в исходниках отображается клинопись вместо кириллицы, тоже самое в командах git show, git diff и т.д. Причина ясна - в svn исходники хранятся не в utf-8 и в оригинале переконвертить их нельзя. Если указать кодировку в `.gitattribute`, как потом правильно настроить синхронизацию, ведь она не будет работать? Есть ли выход из этой ситуации? Хотелось бы что-бы ВСЯ история изменений была в читаемом виде.
2. В статьях в основном описывается разовая миграция через промежуточные bare-репозитории, понадобятся-ли они в вышеуказанной ситуации и как в принципе организовать эту самую двухстороннюю синхронизацию? Через хуки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что эта миграция вам в самом деле нужна? Может проще оставить как было, а в гите (если по каким-то соображениям svn вас далее в самом деле не устраивает) делать все новое?

Comment: Есть задание, и его нужно либо выполнить, либо внятно обосновать что сделать такое невозможно)

Comment: скажите, что придётся фсё переконвертировать в utf8, т.к. даже полу-официальный клиент git_for_windows (начиная с версии 2.11, вышедшей в 2017 году) разучился работать с репами в win1251.  чего уж говорить про гитлаб и прочие браузерные приложения, которые считают что весь мир использует utf8...

Comment: Как минимум нашелся атрибут working-tree-encoding, в котором можно указать в какой кодировке исходники проекта, даже если в разных кодировках. Например, создать файл `.gitattributes` в нем `*.abc text working-tree-encoding=cp866 eol=crlf` `*.xyz text working-tree-encoding=windows-1251 eol=crlf`. И это работает, но только с ревизии, в которой был добавлен файл `.gitattributes` , а все ранние ревизии так и остаются в нечитаемой кодировке. И второе, как этот механизм увязать с дальнейшей синхронизацией?

Comment: @ESkri, даже если щас фсё переконвертить в utf-8, как быть с историей в несколько сотен тысяч ревизий? Там же ничего не изменится.

Comment: Из общих соображений - 1й шаг, SVN репо стоит просто перегенерировать с нуля в utf8 и после тестов, сделать подмену, например на выходных. 2й шаг, единомоментно перенести на гит и забыть про "синхронизацию в обе стороны" - никому она не нужна на самом деле.

Comment: @wolfrevo, вообще-то я имел в виду, что **сотни проектов и ДЕСЯТКИ разработчиков** - это скорее напоминает какой-то кружок авиамоделистов в дворце пионеров. Вам просто не нужна вся эта история коммитов, разработчики в любом случае будут  вынуждены работать с каким-то из *релизов* старого проекта (пракически с нуля). Т.е. все что вам нужно это архив исходников релизов. И даже в этом случае возникнет проблема с наличием старых версий всего окружения для которого когда-то выпустили это релиз.

Comment: @Kromster, а можно уточнить порядок действий по 1-му шагу, что подразумевается под "SVN репо стоит просто перегенерировать с нуля в utf8" ? Речь идет о порядка пятиста проектах в trunk и около 300 тыс ревизий.

Comment: @avp *"Вам просто не нужна вся эта история коммитов"* - очень-очень сомнительное утверждение. Другое дело, что действительно, можно заморозить SVN репозиторий и начать со снапшота в Git - вся SVN история будет под руками - кому надо Blame или еще что-то - посмотреть не супер-сложно.

Comment: @Kromster, ну, для blame hall экзерсисов надо оставить -)

Comment: Если все в trunk, то не имеет значения сколько там проектов, это просто файлы и папки. 300к комитов это конечно немало, займет время.. Порядок действие не подскажу, но на Хабре были статьи про исправление старых SVN репозиториев. Мы например папку trunk сразу не создали, потом через несколько лет ее ретроспективно внедряли переписывая первый Н-цать тысяч коммитов (автоматом, конечно же).

Comment: `как быть с историей в несколько сотен тысяч ревизий? Там же ничего не изменится` - само без вашего участия не изменится )))  нужен скрипт, вытаскивающий из свн (или из гита, если вы уже склонировали), перекодирующий в утф8 и кладущий в другой гит.  все поля коммита (автор, дата, коммент) берёте из источника, перекодируете, сохраняете в гите.

Comment: @ESkri, т.е. Вы предлагаете вместо использования `git svn ...`  создать свой велосипед и при этом увеличить количество ревизий в два раза?

Comment: почему велосипед? разве git svn умеет перекодировать исходники?  коммитов будет столько же, сколько и было

Comment: @ESkri, ни у одной команды git svn (init, clone, fetch, rebase и т.д.) нет параметра перекодировки.

Comment: В этой ситуации подход с постепенным переходом и синхронизацией в обе стороны все крайне усложняет. Куда проще будет за один день загасить svn, перевести все на git и на следующий день начать новую жизнь. *"ВСЯ история изменений была в читаемом виде"* - это подразумевает, сообщения коммитов будут в utf-8 или ASCII. Если кто-то хочет хранить и смотреть файлы в экзотических кодировках или бинарые, то он может воспользоваться соотв. инструментами. working-tree-encoding (и примочки для переводов строк) не нужны.